# Using LDA Model to Obtain Topic Weights for Out-Of-Sample Documents in Python

Tags: python, lda

I am using LDA in Python (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lda) to obtain topics for a set of documents.  I am able to obtain the topics and their weights for the documents that I use to train the model.  Is there a way to apply the model to documents that were not included when estimating LDA?  For example, if I used documents 1-100 to estimate the topics, can I apply the model to documents 101-200 to obtain topic weights for these out-of-sample documents?  Is this possible with the LDA python package I'm using?

If you click on the link I provide above, it gives an example of how to obtain the topic weights for the in-sample documents:

```
doc_topic = model.doc_topic_
for i in range(10):
    print doc_topic[i]
```

Is there a similar function that will apply to out-of-sample documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, after you fit the model you then want to `transform`. See http://pythonhosted.org/lda/api.html#lda.lda.LDA.transform

something like

`topics = model.transform(out_of_sample_docs)`